# C# for while loop bug

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop

If I executed this, it prints hello world 16 times and gets stuck at the while statement.

```
        bool avoiding_cone = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        } while (avoiding_cone) ;
```

If avoiding_cone is false, then it prints out hello world 16 times and exits the loop.

Microsoft, can this behaviour be changed to something more sensible?

Update: I was told this is an lexical anomaly, and indeed it makes sense, and therefore not a bug. By the way, I'm not trying to do anything specific. I like to understand things and not be told to don't worry about it and do something else.

Comment: They are 2 separate loops.  A for loop, then a while loop with an empty statement.  Perhaps you are thinking of a do ... while loop?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a bug, you should pay attention to your logic.
What are you trying to acheive? The while loop looks unnecessary.

You can put the variable `avoiding_cone` inside the `for` loop.
Ex:

```
bool avoiding_cone = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
     if(!avoiding_cone)
          Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

      if(i == 3) avoiding_cone = false; //etc.. use any condition to change avoiding_code value
}
```

Comment: I'm only trying to understand the language and point out there may be a bug. It is more about what the language is aiming to achieve and whether it is valuable.

Answer (score 0):

It never occurred to me the `for` and `while` can be used like this.. Well, I guess this is not a bug, rather a feature.. ;)

I would use `for` by itself, or `do { } while`, I will never use `for` and `while` like this, even if it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told this is a lexical anomaly, and indeed it makes sense, and there is no bug.

I believe it is equivalent to..

```
bool avoiding_cone = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}

while (avoiding_cone);
```